# Python find txt and continue this is causing the fault

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want if find txt and wait program.but program find txt and continue this is causing the fault how can I?

```
    import time
import os
hard_drive = 'D:\\sifreler.txt' , 'E:\\sifreler.txt' , 'F:\\sifreler.txt' , 'G:\\sifreler.txt' , 'I:\\sifreler.txt'
hard_drive1 = hard_drive

while True:
    for i in hard_drive1:
        try:
            sifre = open(i, "r")
            sifree = sifre.readline()

            if sifree == "8da0dd52e2ee6c04528ede0cd84e6770":
                print("True")
                explorer1 = os.system("start explorer.exe")
                time.sleep(1)

        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("File Not Found")
            explorer1 = os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM explorer.exe")
            time.sleep(1)

        except PermissionError:
            print()
```

Comment: What faults are you running into?

Comment: `File Not Found
File Not Found
True
File Not Found
File Not Found` program if True wait program. don't contiune FileNotFoundError

Comment: Sounds like the file `sifreler.txt` isn't being found in `D:/`, `E:/`, `G:/`, or `H:/`.

Comment: yes but there is sifreler.txt in  F:/ I want `sifre = open(i, "r")` Write i instead of `F:/sifreler.txt` or find txt place

Comment: I don't understand you mean by "I want `sifre = open(i, "r") Write i instead of F:/sifreler.txt". What is the full problem you're trying to solve with this code? It sounds like you're missing some logic to make it work for your purposes.

Comment: If you need to include more details, please edit them into the post so everyone else can understand the context. If you can't explain the problem to everyone clearly, then it will be very difficult to help you.

Comment: I edit code try code make sifreler.txt and write in "8da0dd52e2ee6c04528ede0cd84e6770" and save and program run.program find sifreler.txt open and close I want dont close wait find txt place

Answer (score 0):

I solved.edit all code now find txt and read workss yeahh!!!

```
   drive = "D:\\"
        if "sifreler.txt" in drive:
            print("TXT find")
            drive2 = "D:\\" + "sifreler.txt"

        elif not "sifreler.txt" in drive:
            drive = os.listdir("E:\\")
            drive1 = drive

            if "sifreler.txt" in drive:
                print("TXT find")
                drive2 = "E:\\" + "sifreler.txt"

            elif not "sifreler.txt" in drive:
                drive = os.listdir("F:\\")
                drive1 = drive

                if "sifreler.txt" in drive:
                    print("TXT find")
                    drive2 = "F:\\" + "sifreler.txt"

                elif not "sifreler.txt" in drive:
                    drive = os.listdir("G:\\")
                    drive1 = drive

                    if "sifreler.txt" in drive:
                        print("TXT find")
                        drive2 = "G:\\" + "sifreler.txt"

                    elif not "sifreler.txt" in drive:
                        print("TXT don't find")

        sifre1 = open(drive2, "r")
        sifree1 = sifre1.readline()
```